# "CSRF verification failed" when attempting to upload a file or create a folder with filebrowser for Django

Tags: python, django, upload, file-upload

I have installed filebrowser for Django (not filebrowser3) and when I try to upload a file I recieve the following error:

> **403 Forbidden**
>
> CSRF verification failed. Request
>   aborted.
>
> More information is available with
>   DEBUG=True.

The same error occurs when I try to create a new folder which shows that the problem is that filebrowser cannot create files/direcories within my uploads directory. I am using the default settings and have manually created the `/media/uploads` directory with it's permissions set as `755`.

If I upload a file to the directory then file-browser admin page states:

> 1 Item  Folder: 0  Image: 1

I cannot view the image that I have uploaded.

I have the PIL and sorl.thumbnail modules installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably using the development version of Django, which includes quite a lot of extra CRSF security. However it's not released yet so external products probably aren't compatible. You should use the 1.1 version of Django instead.

Comment: Correct! I am struggling with downgrading to 1.1. Is there any way to resolve this issue besides waiting for the app to be updated? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Djangodocs have more information about the new [Django CSRF requirements](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/):

Answer (score 4):

Add to you settings.py this 2 lines:

‘django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware’,
‘django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware’,

Comment: Usually the error will tell you that you need to include the first one, but it will not tell you to include the second one. +1 for listing both here as this solved my issue :)

Answer (score 2):

See here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/ like fitzgeralsteele said.
Hugs.

Example:
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse(‘Hello world’)

Disable the CSRF middleware.

Answer (score 0):

it work adding

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

my forms looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{{formulario}}
<input type="submit" value="Guardar">
</form>
```

in to the  tags on your template file
and verify that 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', is in your settings file, it is in by default